# Collections get loaded even when they are declared as Lazy

Tags: hibernate, jpa

```
@Entity 
public class User {

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { MERGE, PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH }, fetch = LAZY)
    @Cache(usage = READ_WRITE)
    @UserRoles
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>(0);

}
```

Collections get loaded even when they are declared as Lazy, what could be the reason that it is getting loaded even when it is declared as Lazy

Comment: @axtavt: Good call! When Hibernate was new and unusual I've seen how a simple toString() method used for the debug logging would bring a system virtually to standstill by causing hundreds of database reads to occur.

Comment: @axtavt - My console logs from the jboss server, shows sql statements which indicate that these are being loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the JPA 2.0 specification lazy fetching is a hint to the persistence provider.

Section 11.1.6 says:

> The EAGER strategy is a requirement on
>   the persistence provider runtime that
>   data must be eagerly fetched. The LAZY
>   strategy is a hint to the persistence
>   provider runtime that data should be
>   fetched lazily when it is first
>   accessed.The implementation is
>   permitted to eagerly fetch data for
>   which the LAZY strategy hint has been
>   specified.

There are cases in which the provider might determine that it makes no sense to lazily fetch something, or perhaps a provider may not even implement lazy fetching.

The PersistenceUtil.isLoaded methods can be used to determine the load state of an entity
and its attributes regardless of the persistence unit with which the entity is associated.

To be sure you are facing this kind of problem you should use this method. Of course, if a entity got detached, a simple inspection of the lazily fetched field could help as well.

Other than this, I cannot see a particular reason, based on the code posted of why your collections is not being lazily fetched. I think that perhaps the fact that you are using 2nd level cache could be affecting in this case, but this is something I have not verified, it is just a hunch.

**[EDIT-1]**

There is also an issue with lazy loading if you are using final classes. The Hibernate documentation says under [persistent classes](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/persistent-classes.html):

> A central feature of Hibernate,
>   proxies, depends upon the persistent
>   class being either non-final, or the
>   implementation of an interface that
>   declares all public methods.
>
> You can persist final classes that do
>   not implement an interface with
>   Hibernate. You will not, however, be
>   able to use proxies for lazy
>   association fetching which will
>   ultimately limit your options for
>   performance tuning.
>
> You should also avoid declaring public
>   final methods on the non-final
>   classes. If you want to use a class
>   with a public final method, you must
>   explicitly disable proxying by setting
>   lazy="false".

**[EDIT-2]**

Besides this the JPA 2.0 Specification in section 2.1 specifies that entities must not be final:

> The entity class must not be final. No
>   methods or persistent instance
>   variables of the entity class may be
>   final

This same requirement is later specified for embeddables in section 2.5.

I do not have access to the JPA 1.0 specification, but I am quite confident that this requirement applies to it as well. Try it and see if this is the reason and let us know.

Comment: I am using ehcache as the 2nd level cache

Comment: @Joe You might like to check the use of final classes in your model, despite being against the JPA 2.0 specification requirements it also has issues with Hibernate lazy loading. I have updated the post accordingly. By chance do you use final classes for any relationships in your model, more specifically for the relationship in question that is not being lazily fetched?

Comment: I am using Hibernate 3.3.x which is JPA 1.2 compliant

Comment: I do have final qualifiers in the getters and setters, is that an issue?

Comment: @Joe Well, the JPA specification states that neither the class, nor the fields nor its methods should be final. I do not have access to the JPA 1.0 specification, but I am quite confident that this requirement applies to it as well. Try it and see if this is the reason and let us know.

Comment: @edalorzo - Tried removing the final keyword, don't see a difference as of now. I am still investigating it.